# Mendeley iOS alternative 2021?

Tags: citations, journals

I have been using Mendeley to mange and annotate articles for quite a few years, I have built up a big library which I use everyday. Unfortunately Elsevier has stopped support for the iOS app and it is not possible to read and annotate articles on a tablet anymore. Since this is my preference when reading, does anyone know of any mobile based alternatives for Mendeley or will I have to transfer my whole library to Zotero or Endnote to still be able to read on a mobile device? Thanks

Comment: What would constitute an alternative?

Comment: Something that I can read and annotate PDF’s on that syncs with a desktop app to use for writing

Comment: *update* I tried PaperShips an app that claims to sync with Zotero and Mendeley but after paying for the upgrade I found that the app doesn’t sync and it hasn’t been updated for a couple of years, the support emails addresses also bounce. The case is still open!

Comment: Not sure if this satisfies all requirements, so just a comment: What about using zotero and annotate/highlight pdfs with adobe reader? Annotations and highlights can be saved with/in the pdf files. To sync them across devices, save the pdf with the zotero library on a sever that supports webdav. (Perhaps dropbox works? I use my private nextcloud server.) Zotero also allows you to store notes with each reference, which might work as substitute for annotations directly in the pdf.

Comment: (Also, I would prefer zotero over Endnote, because it's open source and developed by an independent non-profit. If they ever stop supporting certain OSes or features, there's at least a chance someone will write a fork. Yet it looks like zotero for iOS is still in beta. // There's also (closed source) paperpile, which focuses on annotations and is geared toward users of google docs. I have only tried it for a few minutes.